# Meteoric Autoform change label type

Tags: javascript, meteor, ionic-framework, meteoric

maybe I'm just to stupid to read the docs right, but I'm currently playing around with the meteoric package of meteor.js (ionic integration).

There is the "meteoric:autoform-ionic" package which controls the forms. I want to change the label type of the form that is generated by the following code:

```
{{> quickForm collection="Todos" id="insertTodosForm" type="insert" template="ionic" }}
```

The docs of the package are not that helpful. they say:

> Support for multiple label types: Inline Labels (default) Placeholder
>   Labels ('label-type': 'placeholder', placeholder: 'Label Here')
>   Stacked Labels ('label-type': 'stacked') Floating Labels
>   ('label-type': 'floating', placeholder: 'Label Here')

I dont know how to integrate this in my template.

Anyone familiar with this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the documentation is implying that you to use #autoForm and apply the label-type and placeholder per field.

I couldn't prove this, but here's an example

```
{{#autoForm collection="Todos" id="insertTodosForm" type="insert" template="ionic" }}
    {{> afQuickField name='name' label-type="floating" placeholder="Name" }} 
    {{> afQuickField name='priority' label-type="floating" placeholder="Priority" }}
{{/autoForm}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include it in your SimpleSchema, eg:

```
name: {
    type: String,
    label: "name",
    autoform: {
      'label-type': 'stacked'
    },
    optional: true
  },
```